# Different behaviour for io in pickle with string content

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, io, pickle, python-unicode

When working with pickled data I encountered a different behavior for the `io.open` and `__builtin__.open`. Consider the following simple example:

```
import pickle

payload = 'foo'
fn = 'test.pickle'

pickle.dump(payload, open(fn, 'w'))
a = pickle.load(open(fn, 'r'))
```

This works as expected. But running this code here:

```
import pickle
import io

payload = 'foo'
fn = 'test.pickle'

pickle.dump(payload, io.open(fn, 'w'))
a = pickle.load(io.open(fn, 'r'))
```

gives the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.8.1\python-2.7.8\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "D:/**.py", line 15, in <module>
    pickle.dump(payload, io.open(fn, 'w'))
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.8.1\python-2.7.8\lib\pickle.py", line 1370, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.8.1\python-2.7.8\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.8.1\python-2.7.8\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.8.1\python-2.7.8\lib\pickle.py", line 488, in save_string
    self.write(STRING + repr(obj) + '\n')
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
```

As I want to be future-compatible, how can I circumwent this misbehavior? Or, what else am I doing wrong here?

I stumbled over this when dumping dictionaries with keys of type string.

My python version is:
`'2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is not supprising, because `io.open()` *explicitly* deals with Unicode strings when using text mode. The documentation is quite clear about this:

> **Note**: Since this module has been designed primarily for Python 3.x, you have to be aware that all uses of “bytes” in this document refer to the `str` type (of which `bytes` is an alias), and all uses of “text” refer to the `unicode` type. Furthermore, those two types are not interchangeable in the io APIs.

and

> Python distinguishes between files opened in binary and text modes, even when the underlying operating system doesn’t. Files opened in binary mode (including `'b'` in the *mode* argument) return contents as `bytes` objects without any decoding. In text mode (the default, or when `'t'` is included in the *mode* argument), the contents of the file are returned as `unicode` strings, the bytes having been first decoded using a platform-dependent encoding or using the specified *encoding* if given.

You need to open files in *binary mode*. The fact that it worked without with the built-in `open()` at all is actually more luck than wisdom; if your pickles contained data with `\n` and/or `\r` bytes the pickle loading may well fail. The Python 2 default pickle happens to be a text protocol but the output should still be considered as binary.

In all cases, when writing pickle data, use binary mode:

```
pickle.dump(payload, open(fn, 'wb'))
a = pickle.load(open(fn, 'rb'))
```

or

```
pickle.dump(payload, io.open(fn, 'wb'))
a = pickle.load(io.open(fn, 'rb'))
```